# How can I use current object as variable

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm a complete beginner at django and currently trying to create a library website. Users can issue books, and I want users who have done so, to see 2 extra buttons: unissue and extend. In my mind, this is what I want to be able to write:

```
{% for b in Borrower %}
{% if b.book == {{book}} %}
{% if b.student == {{user}}%}
           #buttons
{% endif %} 
{% endif %} 
{% endfor %}
```

Obviously the error happens at {{book}} and {{user}} because it cannot parse the rest. I'm not sure what the correct syntax is to access current object and user being viewed.

Comment: Try eliminating the `{{` and `}}` brackets. They are only used when the variable is by itself. Not when they are inside of `{% %}`. Also could you post a full stack trace?